# SOAP Extension not running in .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, soap, soap-extension

So I need a SOAP extension for the project I'm working on. I made a C# class that extends SoapExtension, and added a reference to it in web.config. But it's not being run. The class should mung any data that goes through it, but I can run web services (Using SoapUI) and the output is not munged. I think the problem is either with the config files or the namespace.

Here's my web.config:

```
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true"></compilation>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 <webServices>
  <soapExtensionTypes>
    <add type="MySolution.Common.SoapClass" priority="3" group="High"  />
  </soapExtensionTypes>
 </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Some examples have more stuff in the `type` attribute.

And here's the munging function from my class:

```
   public override Stream ChainStream(Stream stream)
    {
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(mStream );
        sw.Write("<soap>Testing</soap>");
        return mStream ;
    }
```

Obviously this will be replaced once I know it's working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem here. With framework 4.5 you can write whatever you like in the `soapExtensionTypes` section. It is just ignored.